# How to notify bold toolbar icon of contenteditable editor that caret was set to bold text node?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

For example, I have this code:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <button>Bold</button>
</div>
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is <b>bold</b> text.
</div>
```

I put caret inside `<b>bold</b>` and after this "Bold" button should be changed to "active" class (highlighted or something else). How to notify bold toolbar icon of contenteditable editor that caret was set to bold text node?

I know how to detect that caret is inside bold node. I need only notify toolbar button about that. Is there some tutorial or pattern related to this?

Answer (score 0):

MutationObserver will help here.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
```

You can observe the changes (i.e. adding caret) and provide an action to react (i.e. adding a class to specified node).

Comment: grzim, Do you know how this is realized in popular wysiwyg editors?

Comment: back in the days, I was working with one editor, and as far as I remember all was handled with events. You can basically have one event listener in an editor and logic to recognize which part of the text is being changed.